# i create a Plug-in project ,but there is no Plug-in with a popup menu template, how to get a Plug-in with a popup menu template

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, popupmenu

Many blogs show me how to develop an Eclipse plugin from 'Plug-in with a popup menu'  template,  but I can't find the   'Plug-in with a popup menu' template.

How to find the 'Plug-in with a popup menu' template?

Env: java version "1.8.0_221"
     eclipse-java-2019-09-R-win32-x86_64
     Eclipse PDE Plug-in Developer Resources    3.14.100.v20190916-1045

my eclipse plugin project:
[image: my eclipse plugin project]

the blogs plugin project:
[image: the blogs plugin project]

Comment: I guess this template is now called _View contribution using 3.x API_, isn't it?

Comment: The blogs are using older versions of Eclipse. The 'View contribution using 3.x API' example creates a view and has a pop-up menu on the view.  The old example you show uses 'action sets' which are now deprecated.